# Check or Help Me w/ Logic Gate Expression Simplification?

Tags: logic

[image: Image of the Expressions in Question]

These are some expressions that I need to simplify. I've done what I can think to do, but surely they don't all simplify to themselves? Some expertise or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### for `R.R = Z`

logically, it's equivalent to `R = z` and you can prove that by the truth table

| R | R.R |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |

as its logical equivalent is a same input to **2-input AND** gate. which will always give the input.

### for `R.S + R.S = T`

you proved it correctly.

### for `X(bar) + X(bar) . X(bar) = K`

```
X(bar) + X(bar) . X(bar) 
= X(bar) . (1 + X(bar))  // since (1 + anything = 1)
= X(bar) . (1)           // since (1 . anything = anything)
= X(bar)
```

then `X(bar) = K`

### for `X(bar) . Y(bar) . X(bar) . Y(bar) = P`

```
X(bar) . Y(bar) . X(bar) . Y(bar)
= X(bar) . X(bar) . Y(bar) . Y(bar)
= (X(bar) . X(bar)) . (Y(bar) . Y(bar))  // since anything . anything = anything (proved from the truth table at the first one) 
= X(bar) . Y(bar)
```

then `X(bar) . Y(bar) = P`